# Check if item from JSON object is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I thought I could do the following to check if a data value was `null` and then substitute something else.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/parsedjson.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, val) {
            if (data[index].Manufacturers[0].Name != null){
             var manufacturer = data[index].Manufacturers[0].Name;}
             else{ var manufacturer ="MISSING"}
        });
    }
})
```

However, this throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined` when the data value is not supplied in the JSON.

How do you check if there is a value to prevent this from happening?

Comment: check on data[index].Manufacturers.length first

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not sure what you mean, the data returned from my PHP is definitely in JSON format.

Comment: [i think is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770393/javascript-check-if-null-from-json). I hope i helped you

Comment: @jonmrich: Yes, but that's not what you're dealing with. You're dealing with the result of *parsing* that JSON. It's not JSON anymore. It's just JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/parsedjson.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, val) {
            if (data[index].Manufacturers[0] && data[index].Manufacturers[0].Name){
             var manufacturer = data[index].Manufacturers[0].Name;}
             else{ var manufacturer ="MISSING"}
        });
    }
});
```

You have to check also data[index].Manufacturers[0] before getting to name, to avoid null pointers.

Comment: Perfect! I'll accept the answer when I'm allowed. Thanks!